# Can someone explain to me about array.forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have explore a few webs and watch some videos but I couldn't understand how `array.forEach()` works

This is the script that I found regarding that

```
let meals = ["rice", "meat", "salad"];
meals.forEach(capitalize);
meals.forEach(print);

function capitalize(element, index, array){
    array[index] = element[0].toUpperCase() + element.substring(1);
}

function print(element){
    console.log(element);
}
```

Can someone explain to me about how `array[index] = element(0).toUpperCase() + element.substring(1);` and `meal.forEach();` works?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Surely you have noticed that it call the function for each array item. What's unclear about it?

Comment: It should be `element[0].toUpperCase()` instead of `element(0).toUpperCase()`. `element` is not a function it is a `string`

Comment: Can you guys explain to me what does this code mean ```array[index] = element[0].toUpperCase() + element.substring(1);```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is an array function from JavaScript, that is used to iterate over items in a given array.

[`element[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#character_access) will return first character of each array element.

[`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) is function use to convertthe string into upper case.

[`element.substring(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) this will return a string, except for the first character.